# Me salta HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden en Python usando SPARQLWrapper a Wikidata al hacer consultas

Tags: python, error-403

hasta ayer estaba ejecutando mi código en el que realizo ciertas consultas a Wikidata usando SPARQLWrapper y no me daba ningún problema, el código funcionaba perfectamente. Pero hoy estoy ejecutando el código y este no funciona al salirme el error HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Que problema puede hacer que de un día para otro pase de funcionar a saltarme ese error? Os dejo un pedazo de código en el que se puede ver como hago una consulta. Os adjunto también el enlace a GitHub donde se puede ver el codigo completo funcionando perfectamente (https://github.com/AlexInigo94/TFM_Alejandro_Inigo/blob/main/Generador_de_Diagramas_Ontologicos_a_partir_de_un_ID.ipynb)

```
#Se obtienen de las propiedades anteriores aquellas que son object properties. Se almacenan en una lista.
#Aquí se genera la consulta. Esta se hace para ver si la propiedad con la que se esta tratando es object property o no.
sparql= SPARQLWrapper("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""ASK WHERE {
wdt:"""+prop+""" rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty
}   
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(XML)
results = sparql.query().convert()
string = results.toxml()
```

Un saludo